# Adding Column to FosUserBundle Table & Form Symfony 2.8

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, entity, fosuserbundle

I am using Symfony 2.8 and FosUserBundle.
I have the Problem that i cant add new Properties to my Entity.
My Entity User looks like that

```
    <?php
// src/AppBundle/Entity/User.php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Entity\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="fos_user")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\name
     * @ORM\Column(type="VARCHAR")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\lastname
     * @ORM\Column(type="VARCHAR")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $lastname;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        // your own logic
    }

    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    public function setLastname($lastname)
    {
        $this->lastname = $lastname;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

But i get always the Error: 
"AnnotationException in AnnotationException.php line 54:
[Semantical Error] The annotation "@Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\name" in property AppBundle\Entity\User::$name does not exist, or could not be auto-loaded."

Maybe my RegistrationFormType helps because i changed it too.

```
<?php

/*
 * This file is part of the FOSUserBundle package.
 *
 * (c) FriendsOfSymfony <http://friendsofsymfony.github.com/>
 *
 * For the full copyright and license information, please view the LICENSE
 * file that was distributed with this source code.
 */

namespace FOS\UserBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class RegistrationFormType extends AbstractType
{
    private $class;

    /**
     * @param string $class The User class name
     */
    public function __construct($class)
    {
        $this->class = $class;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('username', null, array('label' => 'form.username', 'translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle'))
            ->add('email', 'email', array('label' => 'form.email', 'translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle'))
            ->add('plainPassword', 'repeated', array(
                'type' => 'password',
                'options' => array('translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle'),
                'first_options' => array('label' => 'form.password'),
                'second_options' => array('label' => 'form.password_confirmation'),
                'invalid_message' => 'fos_user.password.mismatch',
            ))
            ->add('name')
            ->add('lastname')
        ;
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => $this->class,
            'intention'  => 'registration',
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'fos_user_registration';
    }
}
```

I Have added both Fields Name and Lastname manually in MySQL.

Which Files did i forgot to edit?

Best Regards,
Thomas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should correct the following:
The Entity definition

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Entity\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="fos_user")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     *@var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name",type="string")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="lastname",type="string")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $lastname;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        // your own logic
    }

    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

      public function getName()
    {
         return $this->name;
    }

    public function setLastname($lastname)
    {
        $this->lastname = $lastname;

        return $this;
    }
      public function getLastname()
    {


        return $this->lastname ;
    }

}
```

Also you do not need to edit the FOSUserbundle FormType, rather in you bundle create a new FormType based on your **User** class.